# How can I correctly upload a file to the Meta Whatsapp API via raw text in postman or an HTTP request from visual studio?

Tags: c#, curl, facebook-graph-api, postman, whatsapp-cloud-api

I started using the WhatsApp API (Meta for developers) and I've been able to send text, and even images or files successfully through links using postman and also from a Visual Studio project I created (C#). The problem is that whenever I try to upload a local file, I keep getting errors! Whenever I use the postman "form-data" template I have no issues, the file is uploaded just fine and I get an ID for the file, but whenever I try to do that with raw JSON code (as I've been doing with messages and link files) I keep getting this error "(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required." although is already specified in the code and even after I've checked all the headers are the same as in the working examples. I have also imported the cURL command in postman, and it seems to work just fine, but again, postman only shows the "form-data" as the body and I can't put the file location manually, only through the form, so I have no idea what's the syntax or how it's actually introduced in code.

This is the sample in raw/JSON that's provided in postman I just changed the file location (I suspect the error is here, maybe the syntax or something else)

```
{    
    "file": "C:/dune2.jpg;type=image/jpeg",
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp"
}
```

I've done the same in C#

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/*****/media");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ******");

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("dune2.jpg")), "file", Path.GetFileName("C:/dune2.jpg"));
content.Add(new StringContent("image/jpeg"), "type");
content.Add(new StringContent("whatsapp"), "messaging_product");
request.Content = content;
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(responseBody);
```

and it shows the same error "(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required" although is already provided. (And the path file and file folders are correct because I checked them directly and also for other tests)

This is the curl command that works well when imported to postman:

```
curl -X POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/****/media' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer *****' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json' \
-F 'file=@"****.jpg"' \
-F 'type="image/jpeg"' \
-F 'messaging_product="whatsapp"'
```

but the file field is transformed to a form field, so it has to be entered like this:

[form-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq3Yv.png)

Comment: Use a transparent proxy such as Fiddler to examine the request from both Postman/Curl and HttpClient, and see what the differences are. Side note: `request` and `response` need `using` to dispose.

Comment: `-H 'Content-type: application/json'` can hardly make sense, if you want to perform a file upload. In your C# code you are using `multipart/form-data`, which would be correct - but I can't tell you if it will also include the necessary `boundary` value, when set like that directly. Often the job of setting the correct Content-Type is left up to the library used to make the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I've tried to run the curl command in my computer, and it works perfectly, also I removed the "Content-type" header from my C# code, and now it only seems that there is a problem with how the file is being codified or an extra parameter that I don't know how to put in the code, because I get the error "(#100) Param file must be a file with one of the following types (here goes a long....list of types)". So I think it may be an issue with a missing parameter that I have to put somewhere in the code, or codify the image differently.